# Saving content in a <div> with jQuery in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery

I have written a tiny bit of code that displays an information box for the users and a button to make this information box go away.

I have placed the code snippet in a Content Editor webpart on the page.

Everything works fine and the box disappears nicely when a user hits the button. But, the hiding away is sadly not permanent. Whenever I or a user reloads the page, the original  content is displayed.

Can anyone help me how I get this new  text to 'stick' ie saving it to the aspx page?

My code is:

```
   <script language="javascript"></script>
   <script src="http://skatshp.ccta.dk/Style Library/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <input type="button" id="loadButton" value="Fjern denne tekst" onclick="javascript:fjernboks()" />

   <script>

   function fjernboks()
   {
   var kontekst = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = kontekst.get_web();
   kontekst.load(web);
   kontekst.executeQueryAsync(succes, fejl);

       function succes() {
           var tekstfelt = jQuery("#infotekst");
           tekstfelt.text(" ");
           alert("Infotekst er fjernet");
       }

       function fejl() {
           alert("Noget gik galt")
       }
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot permanently modify an aspx page on the SharePoint server using JavaScript in the browser this way...

You could implement a flag value in the user's local storage if all of your users' browsers will support it -- or you could use a cookie to track if the user wants this particular item hidden. Then in each case on the page load you would check the flag/cookie value and hide the section if necessary.

Comment: Thank you John. Then I have to rethink my approach. Is there a way to make a JavaScript only run once and not every time the page loads?

Comment: Javascript doesn't really work that way... It runs pretty much by definition each time a browser loads a page. To mimic a scenario where it only works once, you could use the same approach as I suggested in the answer, make a flag value that you store somewhere (local storage, maybe even a sharepoint list) that keeps track of if your script has run or not... Then each time the page loads you would check that flag value wherever it was to see if your script needed to run or not (wrap everything in an if statement)

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much. I'll have to rethink the way I use JS on my pages then :o)